# Why can't apache write to a folder even though it's a member of the group?

Tags: linux, apache, file-permissions

I am using CentOS.

I have a directory such as:

`drwxrwsr-x  2 someuser deploy  4096 Apr 23 23:29 logs`

Apache is a member of the deploy group:

`deploy:x:509:dev,apache`

I believe I'm sure that the user that apache is running as, is in fact "apache":

```
$ ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'
apache   26573  0.0  2.6 429516 13176 ?        S    22:54   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
```

So if the group has write permissions, and the group is `deploy`, and the apache user is part of this group, why can't it write to that folder? If I change the group to be `apache`, then apache can write, but I don't understand why this would be necessary.

Comment: It's a CentOS machine - is SELinux running? If so, you'll need to set the correct httpd read/write context on that directory.

Comment: `/usr/sbin/getenforce` to see if SELinux is active...

Comment: `$ /usr/sbin/getenforce` returns 
Disabled

Comment: Did you restart apache after adding to the `deploy` group? (I wouldn't expect a reboot to be needed) And does the Apache error log give you any details other than 'permission denied'?

Comment: This set me down the right path. I had actually restarted the apache service. When I checked the apache logs, they were empty. It turns out that nginx is handling requests on this server, and PHP is being run via the php-fpm service. Since php-fpm was already set to run as apache, and I already had apache as a member of the deploy group, a restart of the php-fpm service is all that was needed. Thanks for helping me solve this!

Comment: If I want to keep SELinux running (Permissive) how do I "correct httpd read/write context on that directory"

Answer (score 2):

> Did you restart apache after adding to the deploy group? (I wouldn't
>   expect a reboot to be needed) And does the Apache error log give you
>   any details other than 'permission denied'? –  Michael Berkowski

This set me down the right path. I had in fact restarted the apache service. However, when I checked the apache logs as Michael suggested, they were empty. Upon further exploration, it turns out that nginx is handling requests on this server, and PHP is being run via the php-fpm service. Since php-fpm was already set to run as the apache user, and I already had added apache as a member of the deploy group, a restart of the php-fpm service is all that was needed. Thanks for helping me solve this Michael.

Comment: Thanks for the hint on php-fpm. It was exactly my case. More than an hour trying to figure this out..

Comment: Same here, and thank Google for finding this question / answer. I would have never have thought to restart the php-fpm service.